# Heroku TypeScript nodeJs fails because default path /app

Tags: typescript, heroku, deployment

I'm banging my head, because it has to be something stupid I'm doing wrong here. Maybe someone can see the mistake i'm making. I have a procfile with web: node dist/index.js but heroku always looks at /app/dist/index.js and can't find it (because it's not there). Thank you very much

```
2020-11-18T21:46:59.081122+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 3afbbcf4 by user email@gmail.com
2020-11-18T21:46:59.081122+00:00 app[api]: Release v25 created by user email@gmail.com
2020-11-18T21:47:00.477909+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-18T21:47:03.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-11-18T21:47:04.530880+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node dist/index.js`
2020-11-18T21:47:05.990726+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922
2020-11-18T21:47:05.990736+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-11-18T21:47:05.990736+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-11-18T21:47:05.990736+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-11-18T21:47:05.990737+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/dist/index.js'

{
   "name": "adsfasdfsadf",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "description": ".",
   "type": "commonjs",
   "devDependencies": {
      "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
      "@types/connect-redis": "^0.0.15",
      "@types/cors": "^2.8.8",
      "@types/express-session": "^1.17.0",
      "@types/ioredis": "^4.17.8",
      "@types/node": "^8.0.29",
      "@types/session-file-store": "^1.2.1",
      "@types/typescript": "^2.0.0",
      "ts-node": "3.3.0",
      "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "apollo-server-express": "^2.19.0",
      "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
      "class-validator": "^0.12.2",
      "connect-redis": "^5.0.0",
      "cors": "^2.8.5",
      "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
      "express-session": "^1.17.1",
      "ioredis": "^4.19.2",
      "mysql": "^2.14.1",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
      "session-file-store": "^1.5.0",
      "type-graphql": "^1.0.0",
      "typeorm": "0.2.27",
      "typescript": "^4.0.5"
   },
   "scripts": {
      "start": "node dist/index.js",
      "postinstall": "tsc",
      "watch-node": "nodemon dist/index.js",
      "watch-ts": "tsc -w",
      "deploy": "git add . && git commit -m Heroku && git push heroku master"
   },
   "engines": {
      "node": "15.2.0",
      "npm": "7.0.12"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try path "node index.js" instead of "node dist/index.js"?

Or you could try running a one-off copy of your dyno to have it list the directory contents. This would allow you to check if your file is where you'd expect it to be. [Here is more information](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#an-example-one-off-dyno).

heroku run 'ls -al'

Check the path for index.js. You may find that your index.js file is not where you expect it to be. Perhaps it's not checked into git?

---

UPD:
Maybe you'll find solution in [this article](http://www.latrovacommits.com/en/2017/12/14/how-publish-dist-folder-heroku/), "Express with server side building" part:

1. Run `npm install express --save`.
2. Create a new file in root folder called server.js.
3. Create another file in root called Procfile.
4. Open package.json and add to scripts heroku-prebuild and heroku-postbuild.
5. Still in package.json add "node" to engines.
6. Run `git rm package-lock.json`.
7. Then run `git rm yarn.lock`.
8. Finally, `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`. This step is required, so Heroku will download dev dependencies to perform build.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion helped my mind to try something different and now the problem remains, but I have found out something new:

When I do heroku run 'ls -al' I don't see a dist folder. When I do 'npm run postinstall && ls -al' there is a dist folder. However, when I run 'ls -al' after that again the dist folder is gone. It seems the dist folder is being deleted automatically and thats why it cant find the files to run it.

Comment: @Andreas maybe you'll find solution in this article [link](http://www.latrovacommits.com/en/2017/12/14/how-publish-dist-folder-heroku/), espesially "Express with server side building" part:
1. Run `npm install express --save`.
2. Create a new file in root folder server.js.
3. Create another file in root called Procfile.
4. Open package.json and add to scripts heroku-prebuild and heroku-postbuild. 
5. Still in package.json add "node" to engines.
6. `git rm package-lock.json`.
7. `git rm yarn.lock`.
8. `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`.

Comment: Hey chmsv, I don't know what exactly helped, I added a main section to my package.json i deleted package-lock.json and I changed NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION and it started working! Thank you very much.

If you alter your comment, into your answer, I'll accept it right away